# Elixir-Phoenix : Dynamic SCSS rendering

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there any way to render scss dynamicly from a controller by passing new variables for colors.

For example in Ruby on Rails you can use the `Sass::Engine` but i did not find anything for Phoenix

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about shelling out to the `sass` executable using `System.cmd/2` (`System.cmd("sass", ["-i", "input.scss", "-o", some_file])`)? There's no pure Elixir implementation of Sass so calling either the Ruby version or libsass is likely your only option.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'll try something like this. have a nice day